# Telling Plot to style vector-valued black-box functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I write a black-box functions, which evaluates an expensive complex valued function numerically, and then returns real and imaginary part.

```
fun[x_?InexactNumberQ] := Module[{f = Sin[x]}, {Re[f], Im[f]}]
```

Then I can use it in Plot as usual, but Plot does not recognize that the function returns a pair, and colors both curves the same color. How does one tell Mathematica that the function specified always returns a vector of a fixed length ? Or how does one style this plot ?

[image: screen-shot of plot with both curves being the same color]

**EDIT:** Given attempts attempted at answering the problem, I think that avoiding double reevalution is only possible if styling is performed as a post-processing of the graphics obtained. Most likely the following is not robust, but it seems to work for my example:

```
gr = Plot[fun[x + I], {x, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 250];
k = 1;
{gr, gr /. {el_Line :> {ColorData[1][k++], el}}}
```

[image: two images, one with styling applied]

Comment: I don't think there's any documented way to do this.

Comment: I tried running a `Trace[Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -1, 1}], TraceInternal -> True]` to figure out where Mma determines the number of lines and assigns colors/styles - but it didn't make anything clearer. Maybe someone else will have better luck understanding the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility is:

```
Plot[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}] &@ fun[x + I]
```

[image]

**Edit**

If your functions are not **really** smooth (ie. almost linear!), there is not much you can do to prevent the double evaluation process, as it will happen (sort of) anyway due to the nature of the Plot[] mesh exploration algorithm.

For example:

```
fun[x_?InexactNumberQ] := Module[{f = Sin[3  x]}, {Re[f], Im[f]}];
Plot[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, {x, -1, 1}, Mesh -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}] &@fun[x + I]
```

[image]

Comment: If one inserts Sow inside fun, and wraps Reap around the plot, it is seen that for some value of x the function is evaluated twice. I do not understand why, though. Let 

fun[x_?InexactNumberQ] := Module[{f = Sin[x]}, Sow[x]; {Re[f], Im[f]}]

Then

(Reap[Plot[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
         PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}] &@fun[x + I]][[-1, 1]] // 
    Tally)[[All, 2]] // Tally

gives {{2, 78}, {1, 197}}, so there is a room for savings.

Comment: @Sasha Yep. I missed your "expensive function" statement. You may use memoization, though

Comment: This seems to avoid some of the reevals. Pretty cheesy though, unless you go to the trouble of localizing the global variable.  fun[x_?InexactNumberQ] := 
 Module[{f = Sin[x]}, Sow[x]; tagalong = Im[f]; Re[f]]
g[x_] := tagalong
pts = Reap[
    Plot[{#[[1]], g[#[[2]]]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
       PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}] &@{fun[x + I], tagalong}][[2, 
    1]];

Comment: Although not a direct answer to my question, your analysis shows that there is only so much unneeded evaluations I can avoid without overriding automatic subdivision. Accepting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a good solution to this if your function is expensive to compute.  Plot will only acknowledge that there are several curves to be styled if you either give it an explicit list of functions as argument, or you give it a function that it can evaluate to a list of values.

The reason you might not want to do what @belisarius suggested is that it would compute the function twice (twice as slow).

However, you could use memoization to avoid this (i.e. the f[x_] := f[x] = ... construct), and go with his solution.  But this can fill up your memory quickly if you work with real valued functions.  To prevent this you may want to try what I wrote about caching only a limited number of values, to avoid filling up the memory: http://szhorvat.net/pelican/memoization-in-mathematica.html

Comment: Caching will be more useful if the Real and Imaginary parts don't have "interesting points". Plot will try to explore those points for each part. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If possible for your actual application, one way is to allow `fun` to take symbolic input in addition to just numeric, and then `Evaluate` it inside of `Plot`:

```
fun2[x_] := Module[{f = Sin[x]}, {Re[f], Im[f]}]

Plot[Evaluate[fun2[x + I]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

This has the same effect as if you had instead evaluated:

```
Plot[{-Im[Sinh[1 - I x]], Re[Sinh[1 - I x]]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: The reason I can not do this, is that the actual function is defined by numeric integration and has no closed form.