# Detection and styling of multiple functions in Mathematica's Plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597566/) question started me thinking about how Mathematica detects multiple functions being plotted.  I find that I really do not understand the process.

Consider:

```
Plot[{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

I can understand that `Plot` finds three elements in the list initially, but how does it "know" to style `2` and `3` the same?  It is as though there is a memory of what part of the starting list those two elements came from.  How does this work?

Comment: Interesting question, as `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` which is still supposed to expand `Sequence` objects, implying that `Plot` should see 4 items in the list.

Comment: @rcollyer Sequence objects will only get expanded at the first level in a function with the `HoldAll` attribute.  Compare `Hold[{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}]` with `Hold[1, Sequence[2, 3], 4]`.  The same applies to `Evaluate`, e.g. `Hold[{Evaluate[1 + 1]}]` vs `Hold[Evaluate[1 + 1]]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, did not know that. So, the answer is simply that `Sequence` is expanded after the styling has been set up. I'd add that to your answer as it suggest quite clearly what is happening.

Comment: @rcollyer,@Szabolcs To expand the argument of Szabolcs a bit: this is not some special rule,but a consequence of the standard evaluation sequence. Splicing sequences is a part of the evaluation process, and happens also inside heads with `Hold` attributes (you need `SequenceHold` or `HoldAllComplete` to prevent that). But sequences deeper in held parts of an expression are not spliced simply because for that, those held parts should have been evaluated - but they are not, since they are held. So, in  `Hold[{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}]`, the list and its internals are not evaluated, thus the result.

Comment: @Leonid, thanks. Since, I usually don't go near the `Hold` attributes, it didn't occur to me that to expand `Sequence` it would have to evaluate the `List` it was in. But, it is obvious once it was pointed out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it knows that there three arguments just so:

```
In[13]:= Function[x, Length[Unevaluated[x]], HoldAll][{1, 
  Sequence[2, 3], 4}]

Out[13]= 3
```

If x is allowed to evaluate, then

```
In[14]:= Function[x, Length[x], HoldAll][{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}]

Out[14]= 4
```

**EDIT:** One sees it better with:

```
In[15]:= Hold[{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}]

Out[15]= Hold[{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}]
```

in other words, flattening of Sequence requires evaluator.

**EDIT 2:** I clearly missed the real question posed and will try to answer it now.

Once Plot determines the number of argument it builds {{ style1, Line ..}, {style2, Line..}, ... }. In the case of {1,Sequence[2,3],4} we get the following structure:

```
In[23]:= Cases[
  Plot[{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 5}], {_Hue, __Line}, 
  Infinity] /. {x_Line :> Line, _Hue -> Hue}

Out[23]= {{Hue, Line}, {Hue, Line, Line}, {Hue, Line}}
```

When plotting {1,{2,3},4} we get a different structure:

```
In[24]:= Cases[
  Plot[{1, List[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 5}], {_Hue, __Line}, 
  Infinity] /. {x_Line :> Line, _Hue -> Hue}

Out[24]= {{Hue, Line}, {Hue, Line}, {Hue, Line}, {Hue, Line}}
```

because lists would be flattened, just not using the evaluator. So as you see the tagging in the same color occurs because Sequence[2,3] is treated as a black-box function which returns a list of two elements:

```
In[25]:= g[x_?NumberQ] := {2, 3}

In[26]:= Cases[
  Plot[{1, g[x], 4}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}], {_Hue, __Line}, 
  Infinity] /. {x_Line :> Line, _Hue -> Hue}

Out[26]= {{Hue, Line}, {Hue, Line, Line}, {Hue, Line}}
```

I was trying to build a top-level implementation which would build such a structure, but one has to fight the evaluator. For example:

```
In[28]:= Thread /@ Function[x,
   Thread[{Hold @@ {Range[Length[Unevaluated[x]]]}, Hold[x]}, Hold]
   , HoldAll][{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}]

Out[28]= Hold[Thread[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}}]]
```

Now we have to evaluate the Thread without evaluating its arguments, which would give 
{{1, 1}, {2, Sequence[2,3]}, {3, 4}}, where the first element of the list is a tag, and the subsequent once are functions to be sampled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sasha, the votes on this answer clearly indicate it is useful to others, but the behavior illustrated was apparent to me before posting.  What has me guessing is the part hypothesized about by Szabolcs.  If you can explain in better detail or with more authority just how that works, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Sasha How is it possible in *Mathematica* to flatten lists without using the evaluator?

Comment: @Alexey I misspoke, I meant to flatten lists without evaluating it elements, with the idea to wrap HoldComplete around elements of lists, then flattening, and then removing the HoldComplete wrappers. I can post the code if needed, but I am leery to do yet another edit to this question, so please post another.

Comment: @Sasha You mean something like this: `Flatten[HoldComplete[{1 + 1, {2 + 2, 3}, 4}], 2, List]`?

Comment: @Alexey Almost, except that I would replace level 2 with Infinity, so that it handles input HoldComplete[{{1, Sequence[2, 3], 4}, {Sequence[5, {6}], {7}}}] correctly.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you. Now it is clear why `Plot` does not flatten `Sequence`: probably the developer just had specified `List` as the last parameter of `Flatten` but had forgotten about `Sequence`. As I can see it unfortunately is not possible to specify a list of `Head`s in the last parameter of `Flatten`.

Answer (score 8):

It's not that difficult to imagine a process which results in this output.  I don't have additional proof that this is indeed what happens, but it is reasonable to assume that `Plot` loops through the list of functions that were passed to it, and associates a style with each.  Then it proceeds to evaluate each of them after setting a value to the plot variable.  Normally each "function" (element in the list passed to `Plot`) would return a real number.  However, since version 6, Mathematica can handle those that return lists of numbers too, with the flaw that it uses the same styling for the complete list.  Version 5 would throw an error for functions that returned lists.